# RadComboBox PropertyChanged not reflected in Text

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, inotifypropertychanged

I have xaml like so:

```
<controls:RadComboBoxEx ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" 
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" 
                        DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedProject.Title}" />
```

RadComboBoxEx is a local class that extends [RadComboBox from Telerik](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radcombobox/overview) and overrides the default properties with company-wide defaults:

```
this.IsEditable = true;
this.IsReadOnly = false;
this.OpenDropDownOnFocus = true;
this.CanAutocompleteSelectItems = false;
this.StaysOpenOnEdit = true;
this.IsFilteringEnabled = true;
this.TextSearchMode = TextSearchMode.Contains;
```

... and does some additional event handling.

When my application starts up and Projects is populated, this works like a charm.  The user can start typing in the box, see what they're typing, and get a filtered list of items to select.  They select an item and the full title is displayed even if they'd only typed part of the title.

Now...  the user selects Refresh (UI element and method not shown).  The background code goes to the database and picks up a new Project Title.  It keeps the same object, just updates the object properties that changed.  The `PropertyChanged` events fire, the `TextBox` displays updates, the items in the combobox dropdown display the update, ***but the selected item text does not update***.

First I tried adding the `Text` property and binding it to the `SelectedProject.Title`.  Two way binding allowed the text to refresh, but caused all sorts of issues as the values of the objects were being unintentionally changed.  You'd expect `OneWay` binding to work, but it did not take any updates from the DataContext unless `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus`, which isn't really sufficient behavior.

I then discovered that if I set `IsEditable="False"`, the selected item display would update without any Text property binding.  But then the user couldn't see what they were typing when trying to filter the list.  I considered changing `TextSearchMode.Contains` to `TextSearchMode.StartsWith`, but that's only going to be suitable for some of the combo boxes.

I tried forcing `SelectedItem` to `TwoWay` binding and raising an `PropertyChanged` event saying `SelectedProject` had changed even when it had not, and there was no change in behavior.

Obviously the TextBox that is displayed when `IsEditable` is true is not (by default, unless you stupidly bind two way to the `Text` property^) bound directly to the item selected, as you want user typing to connect to the filter, not the selected item.  It does however seem to correctly fill in the full string when an item is selected, so there must be some way to trigger the event when the selection changes.  (Despite my prior failed attempt to force this with a `PropertyChanged` event, it must be so.)

So I brute forced it in my refresh method.

```
Project temp = this.SelectedProject;
this.SelectedProject = null;
this.SelectedProject = temp;
```

This worked!  So somewhere in the event chain inside the control, there was a no change -> no action break in the chain, and it never looked at the sub-properties changing for updating the Text property.

So I have a hack that works for this particular circumstance, but I have to do this in several places, and I'd rather not leave this trap behind for the next dev in our team.  Is there anything I can do in our RadComboBoxEx to get the correct event flow going for this type of change?

Comment: FYI the TextBox exists for debugging purposes only, to prove the data binding is correct on the ViewModel end.

Comment: Try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger` as `PropertyChanged` and `Mode` to `TwoWay` in the binding.

Answer (score 1):

### Official solution to the issue

This issue has been reported in the [Telerik forums](https://www.telerik.com/forums/radcombobox-doesn-t-updates-text-when-renaming-item) before. The official solution to get this to work is by binding the `Text` property of the `ComboBox` in `TwoWay` mode. You did almost the same, but you used the **same** property for binding the display member and the `Text` property. This will not work for your requirements, you have to create **separate** properties.

```
private Project _selectedProject;
private string _selectedProjectTitle;

public Project SelectedProject
{
   get => _selectedProject;
   set
   {
      if (_selectedProject != value)
      {
         _selectedProject = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}

public string SelectedProjectTitle
{
   get => _selectedProjectTitle;
   set
   {
      if (_selectedProjectTitle!= value)
      {
         _selectedProjectTitle= value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

In your XAML code, bind the `SelectedItem` and the `Text` and set the `DisplayMemberPath`.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProject}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="Title"
          Text="{Binding  SelectedProjectTitle, Mode=TwoWay}"
          .../>
```

Whenever you fetch the new data from the database, and your selected item or one of its properties changes, assign the new `Title` to the `SelectedProjectTitle` property. This property is only used to make the updates possible, it does not change any data on your `Project` view models, so you will not run into the issue of unintentional changes.

### Root cause of the issue

The root cause of this issue is the `IsEditable` property. Internally, there is an `Update` method like this, which behaves differently depending on the `IsEditable` state.

```
private void Update()
{
   if (this.IsEditable)
      this.UpdateEditableTextBox();
   else
      this.UpdateSelectionBoxItem();
}
```

The display member of the selected item is displayed by a `TextBox`. If the `ComboBox` is not editable, the text box displays the property defined by `DisplayMemberPath` on the `SelectedItem`. It is updated in the `UpdateSelectionBoxItem` method, but **not** in `UpdateEditableTextBox`.

Consequently, if the `ComboBox` is editable, the `DisplayMemberPath` is disregarded on updates, so the text will stay the same, there will not be any updates from the properties. However, the official solution of course works, as the `Text` property is bound `TwoWay` which will trigger updates.

There is also a reason, why resetting the `SelectedItem` works for updating the text. There are a few triggers that cause an update of the `SelectedItem`, like assigning another item or `null`. This will call a method, which will update the `Text` property explicitly and then call `Update`.

> Can I override the no change -> no event pattern in a child class of RadComboBox?

All the update related methods are `private` or `internal`, but not `virtual`. You will not be able to override the behavior in a subclass, unless you start at dependency property changed handlers, which themselves contain lots of logic, so this apprach is doomed to fail sooner or later.

I think the best way to go from here is to use the official solution, as it is documented and matches the behavior of WPF's own `ComboBox`. In the long run this will most likely save you a ton of maintenance and bug fixes. The key is that you communicate this intended behavior openly and document it for your own derived control, so that all your clients are aware of it.

Comment: Good to have the official answer from Telerik, but this is still a trap that needs to be diffused in every project, not solved in the child class...

Comment: Awarding the bounty anyway, and it is deserved for getting the Telerik answer.